# Filter by field value in a child table

Tags: qgis, postgis, filter, relates

In QGIS, I would like to filter the display of a parent table in (a postgis point theme) by the values in a field from a child table (a postgresql table in the same db). The parent table and child table are related via Primary Key / Foreign Key in postgres/postgis, and that relation has been read into the QGIS project (via Project>Properties>Relations).

When I use the GUI select features by form in the child table and select the value in the relevant field, it does not filter the parent table (point theme) features.

Can this kind of filtering via related table field values be accomplished with the QGIS GUI?

Comment: Is it essential for you to get it with the QGIS GUI? Otherwise, I would suggest you to do the filtering by creating a virtual layer.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion--working through the GUI is not essential for me, but there are other users for whom working with code snippets etc could be a heavy lift.